# What is this plant with purple flowers growing next door?

Tags: identification, flowers, weeds, flowering

Does anyone know what this plant is? It seems to be growing wildly without any help next to our building in Malmö, Sweden

Also, if you can identify it, any idea if I can propagate it and how?

[image: Purple flower with white centre]

[image: Leaves and flower buds]

[image: Close up of leaf]

Comment: Identify, research then propagate...says the person who now has some invasive species in their garden that are really pretty..   :(

Comment: Very sensible, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common name is Apple-of-Peru, botanical name is *Nicandra physalodes*.

It is a member of the Nightshade family, and as the name suggests already it is native to South America. It is introduced in many parts of the world including Europe.

If you want to propagate it, try to collect seeds.